# Birt Dataset oda exception

Tags: java, spring, jsf, birt

I am using `POJO` Data-source and I am creating `Dataset` using all the business logic .I am trying to fetch all the data from `Database` and want to set in particular field. Like I have `hourlyRate` then from database according to employee the `hourlyRate` is fetch by calling service method. All the places where I am calling `getService()`. getting null value.

But it throws:

```
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot execute the statement. 
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ; 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:52)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:84)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:586)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:972)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:503)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1208)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:233)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:178)     
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ExtractionResults.nextResultIterator(ExtractionResults.java:157)     
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:69)     
at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:366)     
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121) 

Caused by: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ; 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.pojo.impl.internal.PojoDataSetFromCustomClass.open(PojoDataSetFromCustomClass.java:194)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.pojo.impl.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:126)     
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doExecuteQuery(OdaQuery.java:480)     
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.executeQuery(OdaQuery.java:444)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:575) 

... 9 more 

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     
at org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.pojo.impl.internal.PojoDataSetFromCustomClass.open(PojoDataSetFromCustomClass.java:180) 

... 13 more
```

BirtInvoiceDataSet class:

```
 public class BirtInvoiceDataSet {


    private IEmployeeService employee;



    public BirtInvoiceDataSet() {
        BirtInvoiceJavaObject birtInvoice = new BirtInvoiceJavaObject();
    }



    @ManagedProperty("#{employeeService}")
    private IEmployeeService employeeService;
    @ManagedProperty("#{timeSheetService}")
    private ITimeSheetService timeSheetService;
    @ManagedProperty("#{timeSheetDetailsService}")
    private ITimeSheetDetailsService timeSheetDetailsService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{invoiceService}")
    private IInvoiceService invoiceService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{projectService}")
    private IProjectService projectService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{projectEmployeeService}")
    private IProjectEmployeeService projectEmployeeService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{companyService}")
    ICompanyService companyService;

    public List<BirtInvoiceJavaObject> getInvoice() {
        List<BirtInvoiceJavaObject> invoice = new ArrayList<BirtInvoiceJavaObject>();

        try {
            System.out.println("getting Dto list");



            //Here I am getting null pointer exception
            List<EmployeeDTO> employeeDtoList = this.getEmployeeService()
                    .getAllEmployees();

            System.out.println("done" + "emplooyeyey" + employeeDtoList);

            if (employeeDtoList == null) {
                throw new MyException(ExceptionCodes.EMPLOYEE_NULL);
            }

            Iterator<EmployeeDTO> employeeIterator = 

                     employeeDtoList.iterator();
            while (employeeIterator.hasNext()) {
                EmployeeDTO employee = employeeIterator.next();
                String employeeName = employee.getEmployeeName();
                ProjectEmployeeDTO emp = null;



                  //Dont know how to get data I have tried a lot. All jar files are available in /WEB-INF/lib folder. 

                  //Here I am getting null pointer exception

                emp = getProjectEmployeeService().getProjectIdByEmployeeId(
                        employee.getEmployeeId());

                if (emp == null) {
                    continue;

                }

                if (employee.getIsEmployeeActive() == (byte) 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (emp.getProjectDTO().getProjectId() == 0)
                    continue;
                System.out.println("Project Id"
                        + emp.getProjectDTO().getProjectId());

                ProjectDTO projectDto = this.getProjectService() 
                               .getProjectById(emp.getProjectDTO()  
                           .getProjectId());object.setEmployeeName(employeeName);

                            object.setHours(hour);

                           object.setPayment(temp.getTime());
                           invoice.add(objet); 
                           Iterator<BirtInvoiceJavaObject> iterator;

public void open(Object appContext, Map<String, Object> dataSetParamValues) {

    List<BirtInvoiceJavaObject> invoice1 = getInvoice();
    iterator = invoice1.iterator();

}

public Object next() {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        return iterator.next();
    }
    return null;
}

public void close() {
    iterator = null;
}
```

This is my `BirtInvoiceJavaObject` pojo class

```
public class BirtInvoiceJavaObject implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String employeeName;
private Double total;
private Integer registrationNumber;

private Date payment;
private Integer hours;
private Integer rate;

public Date getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

public void setPayment(Date payment) {
    this.payment = payment;
}

public Integer getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public void setHours(Integer hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
}



public Integer getRegistrationNumber() {
    return registrationNumber;
}
}
```

And this is my spring-bean.xml

```
    <bean id="birt" class="com.agranee.timesheet.birt.BirtInvoiceDataSet">
         <property name="employeeService" ref="employeeService" />
        <property name="timeSheetService" ref="timeSheetService" />
        <property name="timeSheetDetailsService" ref="timeSheetDetailsService" />   
     <property name="invoiceService" ref="invoiceService" />
     <property name="projectService" ref="projectService"/>
     <property name="projectEmployeeService" ref="projectEmployeeService"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectEmployeeService"   class="com.agranee.timesheet.service.ProjectEmployeeServiceImpl">
        <property name="projectEmployeeDao" ref="projectEmployeeDao" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="projectEmployeeDao" class="com.agranee.timesheet.dao.ProjectEmployeeDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="projectService" class="com.agranee.timesheet.service.ProjectServiceImpl">
        <property name="projectDao" ref="projectDao" />
    </bean>



<!--    User DAO Declaration -->
    <bean id="projectDao" class="com.agranee.timesheet.dao.ProjectDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
<!--     User DAO Declaration -->

<!--     User Service Declaration -->

<!--        User Service Declaration -->
    <bean id="companyService" class="com.agranee.timesheet.service.CompanyServiceImpl">
        <property name="companyDao" ref="companyDao" />
    </bean>

       <!--User DAO Declaration -->
    <bean id="companyDao" class="com.agranee.timesheet.dao.CompanyDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Used tools:

- Maven
- eclipse
- jsf
- hibernate
- Spring3.1.0 & Birt Runtime 4.3

Comment: show `ProjectEmployeeServiceImpl` class. make your question simple by removing usefulness code comments.